# Vim airline displaying issue

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

I was setting up vim-airline and for what ever reason I can't get it to display like powerline. Any help would be appreciated.
.vimrc

```
set noswapfile
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
set laststatus=2 
set lazyredraw
let g:airline_theme             = 'powerlineish'
let g:airline_enable_branch     = 1
let g:airline_enable_syntastic  = 1
let g:airline_left_sep          = '⮀'
let g:airline_left_alt_sep      = '⮁'
let g:airline_right_sep         = '⮂'
let g:airline_right_alt_sep     = '⮃'
let g:airline_branch_prefix     = '⭠'
let g:airline_readonly_symbol   = '⭤'
let g:airline_linecolumn_prefix = '⭡'
highlight constant ctermfg=yellow
```

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: Does anything change if you add `let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1`? Do you have powerline fonts installed on your filesystem? I also have `set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 10`, but your's may be a different approach. Can you choose powerline fonts from `:set guifont=*`?

Comment: I think this, https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts, is where I got my powerline fonts. Was this similar to your approach?

Comment: Neither of those do anything, I use a custom .ttf that I patched to work with powerline. I also tried using the default powerline fonts and nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe it has more to do with your background. Could be setting background of airline. For instance, try `:highlight`. Or, how does your background work? I've never seen that.

Comment: Na I figured it out, the background wasn't the issue I guess the default airline theme didn't color anything. After setting the theme to anything else everything worked the way it was meant to.

Comment: Okay, but it may have been a factor. If I start Vim up with a different `colorscheme`, the default airline theme is effected.

Comment: Please use their issue tracker instead of SO.